# Icono para ventanas con TopLevel

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Dentro de una especie de aplicativo del estilo de un Editor de Texto, abro las típicas ventanas de "Ayuda" y "Acerca de".

Ambas ventanas están realizadas usando el widget Toplevel de Tkinter. Y quisiera ponerles un icono que apareciera en la barra de tareas como tengo hecho para la ventana principal del aplicativo (la de root).

Para la ventana principal (la de root), tengo establecido el icono de esta forma (en este caso, "self", se refiere a ROOT):

```
self.img_logo = PhotoImage(file='img/anonvicom_logo.png')
self.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self, self.img_logo)
```

He probado a hacer lo mismo en la configuración de los dos Toplevel mencionados pero, según parece, por el ERROR que me sale el método "call()" no está disponible para los widgets TopLevel.

He probado, también, a poner de esta forma (por ejemplo, para el Toplevel "ayuda_top"):

```
ayuda_top.iconwindow('img/anonvicom_logo.png')
```

o, así:

```
ayuda_top.iconwindow(pathName='img/anonvicom_logo.png')
```

Pero me da algo como este ERROR:

```
TclError: bad window path name "img/anonvicom_logo.png"
```

También, he usado:

```
acerca_top.iconbitmap('@img/anonvicom_logo.xbm')
```

Pero esta forma, aparte de ponerme la imagen en Blanco/Negro y en negativo, ahora, me está dando este ERROR también:

```
TclError: error reading bitmap file "img/anonvicom_logo.xbm"
```

Al darme este ERROR, se para la ejecución.

La "@" es porque, según parece, para rutas en Linux, haría falta ponerla, y, sino, me sale este mensaje:

```
TclError: bitmap "img/anonvicom_logo.xbm" not defined
```

**NOTA**: como curiosidad, el ERROR de "`TclError: error reading bitmap file "img/anonvicom_logo.xbm"`", se produce cuando ejecuto el aplicativo por el Visual Studio Code. Si lo ejecuto a través del Sublime Text, o por el intérprete de la terminal, se abre sin queja alguna.

Así que, ¿cómo poner un icono de ventana para widgets Toplevel sea o no el mismo icono que el del icono de la ventana padre?
De querer poner el mismo icono del de la ventana principal ¿hay alguna forma, también, de heredar su icono para las ventanas hijo Toplevel?

Entorno empleado: python 2.7.x, Linux Ubuntu 16.04, Tkinter.

---

**Editado**

Para el que le interese como defino el self (el objeto raíz), ahí va:

```
from Tkinter import *


class MiTkinter(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.img_logo = PhotoImage(file='img/anonvicom_logo.png')
        self.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self, self.img_logo)

        # y después todo el código que haga falta
        # ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tk (Raíz) objeto raíz por defecto
    # ==========================================================
    root = MiTkinter()
    # etc, etc, ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a intentar completar la respuesta de ChemaCortes a raiz de los comentarios. En Python 3 efectivamente lo más simple es quizás usar el método `iconphoto` o `wm_iconphoto`, que poseen tanto  `tkinter.Tk`  como  `tkinter.Toplevel`:

- Usar la imagen para el icono de la ventana principal y para todas sus hijas (`default=True`):

  ```
  self.wm_iconphoto(True, self.img_logo)
  ```
- Usar la imagen solo para el icono de la ventana principal (`default=False`):

  ```
  self.wm_iconphoto(False, self.img_logo)
  ```
- Usar otra imagen para una ventana Toplevel (`ayuda_top`):

  ```
  import tkinter as tk

  ayuda_top = tk.Toplevel(self, ....)
  ayuda_logo = tk.PhotoImage(...)
  ayuda_top.wm_iconphoto(False, ayuda_logo)
  ```

El problema es que esto aparentemente no es válido en Python 2, desconozco la razón pero Tkinter no expone en este caso la función `iconphoto` mediante un método de instancia como ocurre en Python 3 (al menos en Python 2.7.14 / Tkinter 8.6 que es donde lo he testado). En realidad el método `iconphoto` simplemente trata de simplificar  el uso de la función `iconphoto` de Tk/Tcl,  usando el método `call` internamente, por lo que podemos hacer lo mismo:

- Usar la imagen para el icono de la ventana principal y para todas sus hijas (`default=True`):

  ```
  self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, "-default", self.img_logo)
  ```
- Usar la imagen solo para el icono de la ventana principal (`default=False`):

  ```
  self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, self.img_logo)
  ```
- Usar otra imagen para una ventana Toplevel:

  ```
  import Tkinter as tk        

  ayuda_top = tk.Toplevel(self, ....)
  ayuda_logo = tk.PhotoImage(...)
  self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', ayuda_top._w, ayuda_logo)
  ```

> **Nota:** he probado esto en Linux (X11), desconozco como se comporta en MacOs. En Windows esto cambia perfectamente el icono de la barra de título, pero el icono usado en la barra de herramientas es el del intérprete Python. Esto se puede solucionar de muchas formas, pero creo que la más limpia es usando [`SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378422(v=vs.85).aspx)de la API de Windows vía `ctypes`:
>
> ```
> import ctypes
>
> id = 'company.product.subproduct.version'
> ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(id)
> ```

Comment: OK. A mí no me funcionaba el `call()` para los Toplevel porque, por ejemplo, para el Toplevel del apartado "Ayuda", en vez de poner tal y como sugieres, es decir, `self.call('wm', 'iconphoto', ayuda_top._w, ayuda_logo)` (obvio el "`.tk`" porque hago el import de otra forma) yo estaba poniendo esa sentencia algo así `ayuda_top.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, ayuda_logo)`. Estaba aplicando el "call()" al Toplevel directamente y tu se lo aplicas a la ventana raíz y luego dentro de los paréntesis indicas el elemento Toplevel y yo señalaba la ventana raíz. Puede que ese fuese el fallo.

Comment: He probado la forma esta que sugieres de vincular un icono diferente al elemento y la forma de vincular el icono de la ventana padre a las ventanas hijo, y las dos formas me funcionan ... :). El otro Toplevel, el del apartado "Acerca de" lo tengo como ventana modal. Esto no tiene mucha importancia, pero, supongo que por eso, no llega a aparecer un nuevo icono para esta ventana cuando la abro sino que sigue como único icono el ya correspondiente a la ventana principal. ¿es así?

Comment: Como última reseña, al definir los dos Toplevel, no había puesto el self tal que así, por ejemplo, `ayuda_top = Toplevel(self)`. He probado a ponerlo o no ponerlo y me funciona de igual forma en ambos casos. Supongo que no influye no poner el self especialmente o, al menos, en estos casos. También, dentro del "call()", no pongo el "._w", es decir, lo dejo así `self.call('wm', 'iconphoto', ayuda_top, ayuda_logo)` en vez de `self.call('wm', 'iconphoto', ayuda_top, ayuda_logo)`. Y funciona bien igualmente. ¿Ese "._w" es algo aplicado, por defecto, si no se pone o es que no influye si no se pone?

Answer (score 2):

El `.call()` lo que está haciendo es invocar directamente al intérprete TCL que está por debajo de *Tkinter* y sólo se puede hacer desde `root` de Tk.

Esta sentencia:

```
self.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self, self.img_logo)
```

equivale a:

```
self.iconphoto(self.img_logo)
```

Además de ser más conciso, este método estará disponible para el resto de ventanas.

Pero también podrías haber dado este icono por defecto para todas:

```
self.iconphoto(self.img_logo, default=True)
```

Los errores que te da parecen que son por usar ruta relativas. Prueba a usar ruta absolutas a ver si funciona.

De todas formas, la mejor forma de poner iconos a las ventanas sería usando ficheros PNG y tener más cuidado con las rutas, algo de esta forma:

```
import tkinter as tk
from pathlib import Path

WORKDIR = Path(__file__).parent
icon = WORKDIR/"img"/"icono.png"

root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap(icon)

about = tk.Toplevel(root)
about.title("Prueba")

about.iconbitmap(icon)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**Editado**: *en el código anterior hay que modificar las dos primeras líneas para que funcione en python2, e instalando el módulo `pathlib2`*:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from pathlib2 import Path

WORKDIR = Path(__file__).parent
icon = WORKDIR/"img"/"icono.png"

root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap(icon)

about = tk.Toplevel(root)
about.title("Prueba")

about.iconbitmap(icon)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Si sustituyo `self.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self, self.img_logo)` por lo que sugieres que es equivalente, osea, `self.iconphoto(self.img_logo)` me da el ERROR `AttributeError: iconphoto`. Creo que el método "iconphoto()" como que no existiese para el elemento ventana raíz. Cuando pongo "root" y tecleo el punto, me salen diversos método de "icon..." pero no el "iconphoto()". Los que me salen son: iconbitmap, iconify, iconmask, iconname, iconposition e iconwindow (tampoco sale nada de iconphoto en esta referencia http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm que igual estoy equivocado en tomarla como tal)

Comment: También he probado a poner con el **iconbitmap()** pero tanto si lo pongo con ruta absoluta o con ruta relativa, me dice `tkinter.TclError: bitmap "/home/RUTA_HASTA_EL_ARCHIVO/img/anonvicom_logo.png" not defined`. Estoy probando con `self.iconbitmap('img/anonvicom_logo.png')` o con `self.iconbitmap(RUTA_ABS + 'img/anonvicom_logo.png')` tras haber hecho un `import os` y `RUTA_ABS = os.getcwd() + '/'`. En ambos casos, como digo, me da el ERROR de `bitmap ...not defined`.

Comment: Primero, prueba mí código a ver qué pasa. Luego, añade tu código más completo, porque no sé cómo has definido `self`.

Comment: Vale, para que veas cómo tengo definido `self`, voy a editar la pregunta y te lo muestro.

Answer (score 0):

disculpen si el tema estaba cerrado pero dejo lo que me sirvió a mí en mi caso particular por si a algún navegante de la red alguna vez lo necesita.

Donde creo el root que irá destinado al TOPLEVEL (root2 y root3). Hecho eso llamo a "iconbitmap". Trabajo en una versión 2.7 de Python. No sé si esta es la mejor forma, pero funcionó sin errores de fondo.

```
def gotoApplication(self):

    root2=Toplevel(self.master)
    myGUI=UseMe(root2)
    root2.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

def gotoApplication2(self):

    root3=Toplevel(self.master)
    myGUI=UseMee(root3)
    root3.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
```